# Is it worth buying a second hand classic road bike for commuting?

Tags: road-bike, commuting-bike, used-bike

I am looking for a substitute for my commuting bike. It is a cheap second hand general store bike. It do the job but just don't worth keep maintaining. But at same time I have to keep my bike outside for 10 hours a day in place where several bikes where already stolen (attached with cheap bike locks but still a fact). So I am afraid of leaving a decent bike there.

I checked second hand bikes pages and looks like there is a lot classic second hand old road bikes for sale really cheap and from big brands.

But I am not sure how much work a bike from 90s need and what I should check if I am buying one or even if it is a good idea.

Comment: It might be worth clarifying what you're asking - I think you're asking if it's worth buying a second hand bike, rather than asking for a recommendation of a particular bike? Changing your title to that question might help you get better responses :)

Comment: Bike thief doesn't really care if you have a grotty BSO or a nicer old bike.  If he wants it, he gets it.   Can you do anything to enhance your security?   If its at work, can you bring your bikes inside?

Comment: @Criggie In my case it is not an option. Maybe in a future. But I am working in huge company the entire building it is starting to become small. I don't feel like it is ok to ask for space for my bike when we are low on space for people.

Comment: @Criggie: How nice your bike is *does* matter, but it's relative: All else being equal, make sure you lock up your bike next to one(s) which look(s) nicer.

Comment: What do you mean by a *road bike*?  For commuting you really want to have a bike with fenders, luggage racks, etc.

Comment: Some steel bike with 90's shimano 105 or shimano 600 is what Id recommend.

Comment: Look for an older touring bike - that will have the fixings to mount luggage one (you don't want to carry everything in a backpack). Get a good lock, and park next to an expensive bike with a weaker lock, or a cheap bike with a $1 combination lock; make your bike look less attractive/harder to steal than the next one, and the local druggies will move on to that bike.

Comment: @gerrit: At least [according to Wikipedia, *road bike* subsumes *touring bike* (or at least some types thereof)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_bicycle).

Comment: @errantlinguist Hmm, I certainly ride my touring bike on surfaces that wouldn't classify as a *road*.  I see the term does not necessarily mean racing bicycle.

Comment: @errantlinguist - A touring bike can be argued to be a road bike, but not all road bikes are touring bikes.  (Far from it.)  The term "road bike" also covers bikes which might be called "road racing bikes" and which do not have accommodations for panniers or fenders.

Comment: @gerrit: Some people ride mountain bikes in places that wouldn't classify as *mountains*. ;)

Comment: @gaurwraith got myself an early 2000 full 105 bike. Really cool the age it is noticeable by some some weird craks when I push pedals hard and bushings not are all that smooth but still worth it. But over all it was barely used it was just keep in a storage for years.

Comment: With cracks I take you mean noises right ? Not cracks in the frame I hope ! Maybe it could improve with some cleaning and lubing after all time. Also cables work, brakes and shifting could improve with some kind of lubing. I've been / am very happy with my two steel + 105 bikes .. and they are not so flashy that you cannot leave them on the streetgenerally,.

Comment: @gaurwraith by cracks I mean noises. Here and there I should look deeper in it as some sound like breaks rubbing the wheel. It is a good looking bike but It have some ugly damaged stickers. It says grisly horizon and have a bear in front XD. The right thing to keep an random robber away.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A (decent) bike from the '90s would not be significantly different<sup>†</sup> from (a decent) one only a few years old except for a small weight difference and possibly lacking [brifters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifter_%28bicycle_part%29#Combined_brake_and_shift_levers), which are de facto standard on road bikes these days. This statement is of course excepting top-of-the-line superbikes made of carbon fiber and dragon's blood.

- Check it for stuff like rust in hard-to-see places (small bolts etc.): This is a good sign of how well (or rather poorly) the bike was taken care of. If there is no or minimal rust, it's probably been taken care of well enough.
- [Look over the frame for any signs of crashes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/4685/8685): Big dents, cracks, fissures, etc.
- Check if the headset wobbles or not: It shouldn't, and if it does, it might need to be replaced, which would be very expensive.
- [Check how worn the chain is](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/2787/8685): If it looks horrible and probably has never been changed, that's a warning sign.
- [Check the teeth on the front chainring(s)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/429/8685): If they are starting to look like shark fins, the chainring will need to be replaced.
- And of course, just ride the thing and see how it feels.

---

<sup>†</sup> "Significantly different" means from a mechanical/engineering perspective: IMHO, some of the ugliest bikes I've ever seen were from the '90s.

Comment: Rust: Even my 2009 aluminium bicycle has superficial rust on the bolts. I’d still consider it in very good condition. Chain: If only the chain is worn it’s a <15€ maintenance cost. If it’s the first chain the rest can still be in good condition. Headset: Could just need tightening and grease.

  I’d look at the usual wear&tear components: Cables, brake pads, saddle, bar tape, tires, chain … if several or all of these need replacement it can get expensive and work intensive.

Comment: Okay, I guess I went overboard with the "*no* rust" condition; Amending.

Comment: Some 90s bikes also have different wheel spacing in the rear. 126 mm road was still available in the 90s.

Comment: Also, Shimano/Microshift do make 7 speed+ brifters now, so its not too bad to add them on afterwards if you want to.

Comment: @Batman: Good points, but they don't actually count *against* buying a '90s bike as long as the obsolete parts are still in good working order (it's another matter if they need replacing, of course). **Disclaimer:** This is coming from someone who laments the disappearance of 10-speed down-tube shifters.

Comment: @errantlinguist - who said you can't get 10 speed down-tube (DT) shifters?  10 speed DT shifters are still available along with 9 and 8 speed.  <= 7 speed may be hard to find now.

Comment: @Rider_X: Really?-- Where? The closest I've been able to find is a 9-speed in the back with a single chainring, albeit with the shifter always mounted on the stem.

Comment: @errantlinguist - Lots of options online.  [Here is one](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ca/en/s?q=downtube+shifter).  [Here is another [5-9 spd](http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/components/shifting-freewheels-cassettes/shifters/dia-compe-ene-w-dt-shifters.html)].

Comment: @Rider_X: I meant bikes. I don't want to put together my own bike just because I like old-fashioned stuff, and I don't want to spend €300 on brifters just to throw them away.

Answer (score 2):

@errantlinguist gives some excellent points, but I have a couple to add.

- Make sure you have [700C wheels not 27" wheels](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html).  I have only been able to find a single tire in my LBS to fit 27" wheels.
- As @errantlinguist mentioned, biffers.  This is a huge regression.  To the extent, that it changes the way the entire bike feels.  I have switched to flat bars (at great expense) to avoid bad 80s/90s biffers.

In addition to the purchase price, plan on spending $20 - $200 to fix things that need tweaking.

- Brake pads in particular, don't stand the test of time.  Over 10 years, even unused pads will harden and become less sticky.  Replace these right away.
- Adding new bar tape is a great way to freshen up a new bike.
- If you ride clipless, you will probably want to add the same kind of pedals you have on your main bike.  This makes switching less of a mental jump.  I run crankbros eggbeaters on all of my bikes.  [image]

Comment: It's not clear why you added the big photo of the pedal since that seems like such a minor point of your answer. I don't think it's that important to run the same pedals on road and commute bikes, I run SPD's on my commute bike (for walkability and "normal" looking shoes), and Looks on my road bike and have no problem at all switching -- the biggest mental leap for me is switching from the commute bike with extra cross levers for braking and the road bike with only STI levers.

Comment: I don't know where you live, but here, the 2 LBS's and even Wal-Mart have good-enough-for-commuting 27" tires for my road bike, in stock.  The selection and prices aren't as good as 26" or 700mm, but not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

It will need much work and VERY hard to find parts, been there done that after my nice bike was stolen with a crap lock. Just get a UBERKILL LOCK. The thief will not want to mess with your bike and just go to the next lock he sees.

Comment: You do realize that a *crazy uberkill lock* will cost almost as much as a used bike, and weigh a lot, besides?  I like the "park next to a more expensive bike" technique.  It works for cars, too.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! Do not use profanity on the site, we are alerted to it in [Charcoal HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq)  and have to clean it up.

Comment: @Jeffiekins yes but you only have to buy it once and it is provably will last through several bikes. Also a cheap lock potentially can make you spend double (triple for a friend of mine until he learned the lesson)

Comment: What does "uberkill lock" mean?